# O que significa isso no reactjs // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export

Tags: react

Pessoal sempre que crio uma função igual essa embaixo ele fica em amarelo alerta só sai quando eu acrescento esse comentário que o vscode me mostra alguém sabe pq?

```
import React from 'react'
import './FeaturedMovie.css'

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default () => {
  return(
    <div>Olá</div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente os componentes em `REACT` possui nome, no seu caso pergunta não tem nome e por padrão todos os tipos anonimos (aqueles que não tem nome) são **proibidos**, mas, com essa configuração acaba aceitando esse tipo de importação de um componente em `REACT`.

Em [referencia](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md) diz em sua tradução segundo paragrafo: "*Garantir que as exportações padrões sejam nomeadas ajudam a melhorar a capacidade de resposta da base de código, incentivando a reutilização do mesmo identificador para a exportação padrão do módulo em seu site de declaração e em seus sites de importação.*", ou seja, é uma boa pratica nomear (ter nomes de funções declarado explicitamente) para que isso se torna um trabalho fácil em sua declaração, na importação e tem um caracter de otimizar o seu código.

Esse tipo de declaração não é usual em `REACT`, ou seja, o padrão utilizado é com nomes, já vi tal declaração em `VueJS` é um padrão lá talvez, então a resposta faz referencia a biblioteca `REACT` como tag anexada na pergunta, não sendo regra geral no meu entender.

Usualmente todos os desenvolvedores em `REACT` utilizam nomes explicitos e fácil de entender, exemplo:

```
export function App() {
    return (
        <div> Aplicativo </div>
    )
}
```

isso denota que o componente traz alguma funcionalidade importante e real para o sistema, diferente de um `default = () => {}` que traz uma confusão desnecessária, falta de clareza e pior no momento da sua importação terá que inventar um nome, não é melhor ter o nome? (*A resposta é sim, é melhor já ter um nome declarado*).

Algumas formas de declaração falhas e funcionais:

Falhas:

```
export default []  

export default () => {}    

export default class {}    

export default function () {}    

/* eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export:[2, {"allowCallExpression": false}]*/
export default foo(bar)    

export default 123  

export default {}    

export default new Foo()
```

Funcional (*apesar de que algumas utilizam o artificio de suprimir o problema.*)

```
const foo = 123
export default foo

export default class MyClass() {}

export default function foo() {}

/*eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export: [2,{"allowArray": true}]*/
export default []

/*eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export: [2,{"allowArrowFunction": true}]*/
export default () => {}

/*eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export: [2,{"allowAnonymousClass": true}]*/
export default class {}

/*eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export: [2, {"allowAnonymousFunction": true}]*/
export default function () {}

export default foo(bar)

/*eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export:[2,{"allowLiteral": true}]*/
export default 123

/*eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export:[2,{"allowObject": true}]*/
export default {}

/* eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export:[2,{"allowNew": true}]*/
export default new Foo()
```

Entao crie componentes em `REACT` com ***nome***.

Referencia: [import/no-anonymous-default-export](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md)